# Unity Android IL2CPP did not run properly Building 64bit aab Error

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to build my Unity3D app as a .aab 64 bits as Android Play Store requires this for new submissions now. Unfortunately i get errors and the build fails
I use android NDK r16b and Unity 2019.2.14f1
[buildErrorSnap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMJoy.png)

The detailed error logs :

Failed running C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\il2cpp/build/il2cpp.exe --convert-to-cpp --emit-null-checks --enable-array-bounds-check --dotnetprofile="unityaot" --compile-cpp --libil2cpp-static --platform="Android" --architecture="ARM64" --configuration="Release" --outputpath="F:\Dev\games\Motor\Motor Hero\Temp\StagingArea\assets\bin\Data\Native\arm64-v8a\libil2cpp.so" --cachedirectory="F:\Dev\games\Motor\Motor Hero\Assets..\Library\il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache" --additional-include-directories="C:/Program Files/Unity/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Tools\bdwgc/include" --additional-include-directories="C:/Program Files/Unity/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Tools\libil2cpp/include" --tool-chain-path="F:/Android/android-ndk-r16b" --profiler-report --map-file-parser="C:/Program Files/Unity/Editor/Data/Tools/MapFileParser/MapFileParser.exe" --directory="F:/Dev/games/Motor/Motor Hero/Temp/StagingArea/assets/bin/Data/Managed" --generatedcppdir="F:/Dev/games/Motor/Motor Hero/Temp/StagingArea/Il2Cpp/il2cppOutput"

stdout:
Building libil2cpp.so with AndroidToolChain
    Output directory: F:\Dev\games\Motor\Motor Hero\Temp\StagingArea\assets\bin\Data\Native\arm64-v8a
    Cache directory: F:\Dev\games\Motor\Motor Hero\Library\il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a\il2cpp_cache
ObjectFiles: 170 of which compiled: 0
Total compilation time: 13949 milliseconds.
il2cpp.exe didn't catch exception: Unity.IL2CPP.Building.BuilderFailedException: F:\Android\android-ndk-r16b\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++ @"C:\Users\msi\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp5DE1.tmp" -o "F:\Dev\games\Motor\Motor Hero\Library\il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a\il2cpp_cache\linkresult_7FBA243BFAB4E8AD2A715B8772A32C57\libil2cpp.so" -shared -Wl,-soname,libil2cpp.so -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--build-id --sysroot "F:\Android\android-ndk-r16b\platforms\android-21\arch-arm64" -gcc-toolchain "F:\Android\android-ndk-r16b\toolchains\aarch64-linux-android-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64" -target aarch64-none-linux-android -Wl,--wrap,sigaction -L "F:\Android\android-ndk-r16b\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.9\libs\arm64-v8a" -lgnustl_static -latomic -llog -rdynamic -fuse-ld=bfd.exe

F:/Dev/games/Motor/Motor Hero/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/65EA55399EDDD9C1E6B93BBDF5D84D8B.o: In function `Externs_GADUCreateRequest_m61D77A365937465FEF5BDB47E1B50BC05626A308':
F:\Dev\games\Motor\Motor Hero\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:10279: undefined reference to`GADUCreateRequest'
F:/Dev/games/Motor/Motor Hero/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/65EA55399EDDD9C1E6B93BBDF5D84D8B.o: In function `Externs_GADUAddTestDevice_mF970064A6D15C88CD2D88735D65AD9B8FE6F570D':
F:\Dev\games\Motor\Motor Hero\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:10294: undefined reference to`GADUAddTestDevice'
F:/Dev/games/Motor/Motor Hero/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/65EA55399EDDD9C1E6B93BBDF5D84D8B.o: In function `Externs_GADUAddKeyword_m5BFA76810C1309EDA8EE7B52E67528B89417C109':
F:\Dev\games\Motor\Motor Hero\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:10312: undefined reference to`GADUAddKeyword'
F:/Dev/games/Motor/Motor Hero/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/65EA55399EDDD9C1E6B93BBDF5D84D8B.o: In function `Externs_GADUSetBirthday_m81B701C8D65D2BABA70FED0E809D1B19D1F8231A':
F:\Dev\games\Motor\Motor Hero\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:10326: undefined reference to`GADUSetBirthday'
F:/Dev/games/Motor/Motor Hero/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/65EA55399EDDD9C1E6B93BBDF5D84D8B.o: In function `Externs_GADUSetGender_m19C045B840416A261E5CBE9124F3EA743C44FA7A':
F:\Dev\games\Motor\Motor Hero\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:10336: undefined reference to`GADUSetGender'
F:/Dev/games/Motor/Motor Hero/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/65EA55399EDDD9C1E6B93BBDF5D84D8B.o: In function `Externs_GADUTagForChildDirectedTreatment_m3CB27315E7B4BB787D7515678539E4A98B1B7021':
F:\Dev\games\Motor\Motor Hero\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:10346: undefined reference to`GADUTagForChildDirectedTreatment'
F:/Dev/games/Motor/Motor Hero/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/65EA55399EDDD9C1E6B93BBDF5D84D8B.o: In function `Externs_GADUSetExtra_mDF520237016C54E1B768946F29C5C3289C50D22C':
F:\Dev\games\Motor\Motor Hero\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:10364: undefined reference to`GADUSetExtra'
F:/Dev/games/Motor/Motor Hero/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/65EA55399EDDD9C1E6B93BBDF5D84D8B.o: In function `Externs_GADUSetRequestAgent_m3FCD65589957B6E633E63A30809996F3EEEAFDA3':
F:\Dev\games\Motor\Motor Hero\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:10386: undefined reference to`GADUSetRequestAgent'
F:/Dev/games/Motor/Motor Hero/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/65EA55399EDDD9C1E6B93BBDF5D84D8B.o: In function `Externs_GADURelease_m1BED0763249D45EE9EE992220E05D6249EE9DD8B':
F:\Dev\games\Motor\Motor Hero\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:10400: undefined reference to`GADURelease'
F:/Dev/games/Motor/Motor Hero/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/65EA55399EDDD9C1E6B93BBDF5D84D8B.o: In function `Externs_GADUCreateBannerView_mF009E9D6DA904EFB5AE236A001306C105F7DE18A':
F:\Dev\games\Motor\Motor Hero\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:10414: undefined reference to`GADUCreateBannerView'
F:/Dev/games/Motor/Motor Hero/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/65EA55399EDDD9C1E6B93BBDF5D84D8B.o: In function `Externs_GADUCreateSmartBannerView_m740315A1FDA7EA41A65076FDDBBE8A055D0E8E6E':
F:\Dev\games\Motor\Motor Hero\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:10433: undefined reference to`GADUCreateSmartBannerView'
F:/Dev/games/Motor/Motor Hero/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/65EA55399EDDD9C1E6B93BBDF5D84D8B.o: In function `Externs_GADUSetBannerCallbacks_mC35B5D12F9D1631C3F3EA9D285F98481EEBB9939':
F:\Dev\games\Motor\Motor Hero\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:10468: undefined reference to`GADUSetBannerCallbacks'
F:/Dev/games/Motor/Motor Hero/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/65EA55399EDDD9C1E6B93BBDF5D84D8B.o: In function `Externs_GADUHideBannerView_m98F14AB10441FF109F397EBC8D35AAE5210E412C':
F:\Dev\games\Motor\Motor Hero\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:10478: undefined reference to`GADUHideBannerView'
F:/Dev/games/Motor/Motor Hero/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/65EA55399EDDD9C1E6B93BBDF5D84D8B.o: In function `Externs_GADUShowBannerView_m324B7446D156CE64950F87CB8747E1131CFD5CF9':
F:\Dev\games\Motor\Motor Hero\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:10488: undefined reference to`GADUShowBannerView'
F:/Dev/games/Motor/Motor Hero/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/65EA55399EDDD9C1E6B93BBDF5D84D8B.o: In function `Externs_GADURemoveBannerView_m74401F0FD02948A69406959FAEE8561EDE3834E4':
F:\Dev\games\Motor\Motor Hero\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:10498: undefined reference to`GADURemoveBannerView'
F:/Dev/games/Motor/Motor Hero/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/65EA55399EDDD9C1E6B93BBDF5D84D8B.o: In function `Externs_GADURequestBannerAd_mB852D12FE4402343C74F3A3BBAE4622CEC808F65':
F:\Dev\games\Motor\Motor Hero\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:10508: undefined reference to`GADURequestBannerAd'
F:/Dev/games/Motor/Motor Hero/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/65EA55399EDDD9C1E6B93BBDF5D84D8B.o: In function `Externs_GADUCreateInterstitial_mB8318F5222244B6E4CF4A2B5CC7AAADC160D6535':
F:\Dev\games\Motor\Motor Hero\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:10522: undefined reference to`GADUCreateInterstitial'
F:/Dev/games/Motor/Motor Hero/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/65EA55399EDDD9C1E6B93BBDF5D84D8B.o: In function `Externs_GADUSetInterstitialCallbacks_m91BD006D7D852FAC60A3ED4A2635E2B0A2C0ADB4':
F:\Dev\games\Motor\Motor Hero\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:10557: undefined reference to`GADUSetInterstitialCallbacks'
F:/Dev/games/Motor/Motor Hero/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/65EA55399EDDD9C1E6B93BBDF5D84D8B.o: In function `Externs_GADUInterstitialReady_m52F9F1C9A85AA9D9FFB58EB2C2A5822924DCF92F':
F:\Dev\games\Motor\Motor Hero\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:10567: undefined reference to`GADUInterstitialReady'
F:/Dev/games/Motor/Motor Hero/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/65EA55399EDDD9C1E6B93BBDF5D84D8B.o: In function `Externs_GADUShowInterstitial_m568E4C76539013D3F015430FBF2B0C5B453CFFDA':
F:\Dev\games\Motor\Motor Hero\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:10578: undefined reference to`GADUShowInterstitial'
F:/Dev/games/Motor/Motor Hero/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/65EA55399EDDD9C1E6B93BBDF5D84D8B.o: In function `Externs_GADURequestInterstitial_mF1D8FEC98F30C96935DB968B0F57C9A2813A38D9':
F:\Dev\games\Motor\Motor Hero\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:10588: undefined reference to`GADURequestInterstitial'
F:/Dev/games/Motor/Motor Hero/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/65EA55399EDDD9C1E6B93BBDF5D84D8B.o: In function `Externs_GADUCreateRewardBasedVideoAd_m7D17194D7657261A1C86C5CF5709ACBEA8908E77':
F:\Dev\games\Motor\Motor Hero\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:10598: undefined reference to`GADUCreateRewardBasedVideoAd'
F:/Dev/games/Motor/Motor Hero/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/65EA55399EDDD9C1E6B93BBDF5D84D8B.o: In function `Externs_GADURewardBasedVideoAdReady_m5572DC5E125F83C3DA957477E68FA7DA7E68E85E':
F:\Dev\games\Motor\Motor Hero\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:10609: undefined reference to`GADURewardBasedVideoAdReady'
F:/Dev/games/Motor/Motor Hero/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/65EA55399EDDD9C1E6B93BBDF5D84D8B.o: In function `Externs_GADUShowRewardBasedVideoAd_mC85F76B9F13314CC492F49095B9A5FCA7D41066E':
F:\Dev\games\Motor\Motor Hero\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:10620: undefined reference to`GADUShowRewardBasedVideoAd'
F:/Dev/games/Motor/Motor Hero/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/65EA55399EDDD9C1E6B93BBDF5D84D8B.o: In function `Externs_GADURequestRewardBasedVideoAd_mBB76115890E85E118C704D465D8CE25DB0E2E170':
F:\Dev\games\Motor\Motor Hero\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:10634: undefined reference to`GADURequestRewardBasedVideoAd'
F:/Dev/games/Motor/Motor Hero/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/65EA55399EDDD9C1E6B93BBDF5D84D8B.o: In function `Externs_GADUSetRewardBasedVideoAdCallbacks_mA388DE47BE6175249E1AEE1CF3744F9D254B41F6':
F:\Dev\games\Motor\Motor Hero\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:10676: undefined reference to`GADUSetRewardBasedVideoAdCallbacks'
F:/Dev/games/Motor/Motor Hero/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/65EA55399EDDD9C1E6B93BBDF5D84D8B.o: In function `Externs_GADURelease_m1BED0763249D45EE9EE992220E05D6249EE9DD8B':
F:\Dev\games\Motor\Motor Hero\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:10400: undefined reference to`GADURelease'
F:/Dev/games/Motor/Motor Hero/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/65EA55399EDDD9C1E6B93BBDF5D84D8B.o: In function `Externs_GADUCreateInterstitial_mB8318F5222244B6E4CF4A2B5CC7AAADC160D6535':
F:\Dev\games\Motor\Motor Hero\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:10522: undefined reference to`GADUCreateInterstitial'
F:/Dev/games/Motor/Motor Hero/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/65EA55399EDDD9C1E6B93BBDF5D84D8B.o: In function `Externs_GADURelease_m1BED0763249D45EE9EE992220E05D6249EE9DD8B':
F:\Dev\games\Motor\Motor Hero\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:10400: undefined reference to`GADURelease'
F:/Dev/games/Motor/Motor Hero/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/65EA55399EDDD9C1E6B93BBDF5D84D8B.o: In function `Externs_GADURequestInterstitial_mF1D8FEC98F30C96935DB968B0F57C9A2813A38D9':
F:\Dev\games\Motor\Motor Hero\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:10588: undefined reference to`GADURequestInterstitial'
F:/Dev/games/Motor/Motor Hero/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/65EA55399EDDD9C1E6B93BBDF5D84D8B.o: In function `Externs_GADURelease_m1BED0763249D45EE9EE992220E05D6249EE9DD8B':
F:\Dev\games\Motor\Motor Hero\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:10400: undefined reference to`GADURelease'
F:/Dev/games/Motor/Motor Hero/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/65EA55399EDDD9C1E6B93BBDF5D84D8B.o: In function `Externs_GADUCreateRequest_m61D77A365937465FEF5BDB47E1B50BC05626A308':
F:\Dev\games\Motor\Motor Hero\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:10279: undefined reference to`GADUCreateRequest'
F:/Dev/games/Motor/Motor Hero/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/65EA55399EDDD9C1E6B93BBDF5D84D8B.o: In function `Externs_GADUAddKeyword_m5BFA76810C1309EDA8EE7B52E67528B89417C109':
F:\Dev\games\Motor\Motor Hero\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:10312: undefined reference to`GADUAddKeyword'
F:/Dev/games/Motor/Motor Hero/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/65EA55399EDDD9C1E6B93BBDF5D84D8B.o: In function `Externs_GADUAddTestDevice_mF970064A6D15C88CD2D88735D65AD9B8FE6F570D':
F:\Dev\games\Motor\Motor Hero\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:10294: undefined reference to`GADUAddTestDevice'
F:/Dev/games/Motor/Motor Hero/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/65EA55399EDDD9C1E6B93BBDF5D84D8B.o: In function `Externs_GADUSetBirthday_m81B701C8D65D2BABA70FED0E809D1B19D1F8231A':
F:\Dev\games\Motor\Motor Hero\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:10326: undefined reference to`GADUSetBirthday'
F:/Dev/games/Motor/Motor Hero/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/65EA55399EDDD9C1E6B93BBDF5D84D8B.o: In function `Externs_GADUSetGender_m19C045B840416A261E5CBE9124F3EA743C44FA7A':
F:\Dev\games\Motor\Motor Hero\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:10336: undefined reference to`GADUSetGender'
F:/Dev/games/Motor/Motor Hero/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/65EA55399EDDD9C1E6B93BBDF5D84D8B.o: In function `Externs_GADUTagForChildDirectedTreatment_m3CB27315E7B4BB787D7515678539E4A98B1B7021':
F:\Dev\games\Motor\Motor Hero\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:10346: undefined reference to`GADUTagForChildDirectedTreatment'
F:/Dev/games/Motor/Motor Hero/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/65EA55399EDDD9C1E6B93BBDF5D84D8B.o: In function `Externs_GADUSetRequestAgent_m3FCD65589957B6E633E63A30809996F3EEEAFDA3':
F:\Dev\games\Motor\Motor Hero\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:10386: undefined reference to`GADUSetRequestAgent'
F:/Dev/games/Motor/Motor Hero/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/65EA55399EDDD9C1E6B93BBDF5D84D8B.o: In function `Externs_GADUInterstitialReady_m52F9F1C9A85AA9D9FFB58EB2C2A5822924DCF92F':
F:\Dev\games\Motor\Motor Hero\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:10567: undefined reference to`GADUInterstitialReady'
F:/Dev/games/Motor/Motor Hero/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/65EA55399EDDD9C1E6B93BBDF5D84D8B.o: In function `Externs_GADUShowInterstitial_m568E4C76539013D3F015430FBF2B0C5B453CFFDA':
F:\Dev\games\Motor\Motor Hero\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:10578: undefined reference to`GADUShowInterstitial'
F:/Dev/games/Motor/Motor Hero/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/65EA55399EDDD9C1E6B93BBDF5D84D8B.o: In function `Externs_GADURelease_m1BED0763249D45EE9EE992220E05D6249EE9DD8B':
F:\Dev\games\Motor\Motor Hero\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:10400: undefined reference to`GADURelease'
F:\Dev\games\Motor\Motor Hero\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Assembly-CSharp1.cpp:10400: undefined reference to `GADURele

Exception: C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\il2cpp/build/il2cpp.exe did not run properly!
UnityEditorInternal.Runner.RunProgram (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, System.String exe, System.String args, System.String workingDirectory, UnityEditor.Scripting.Compilers.CompilerOutputParserBase parser) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/BuildUtils.cs:128)
UnityEditorInternal.Runner.RunManagedProgram (System.String exe, System.String args, System.String workingDirectory, UnityEditor.Scripting.Compilers.CompilerOutputParserBase parser, System.Action`1[T] setupStartInfo) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/BuildUtils.cs:71)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder.RunIl2CppWithArguments (System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] arguments, System.Action`1[T] setupStartInfo, System.String workingDirectory) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:503)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder.ConvertPlayerDlltoCpp (System.String inputDirectory, System.String outputDirectory, System.String workingDirectory, System.Boolean platformSupportsManagedDebugging) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:484)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder.Run () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:334)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPUtils.RunIl2Cpp (System.String tempFolder, System.String stagingAreaData, UnityEditorInternal.IIl2CppPlatformProvider platformProvider, System.Action`1[T] modifyOutputBeforeCompile, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry runtimeClassRegistry) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:63)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.RunIl2Cpp.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <21da158cd428404389e0b5a08ba9ea0a>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <21da158cd428404389e0b5a08ba9ea0a>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <21da158cd428404389e0b5a08ba9ea0a>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at <21da158cd428404389e0b5a08ba9ea0a>:0)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/PostprocessBuildPlayer.cs:281)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/IMGUI/GUIUtility.cs:179)

UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 3 errors
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x00242] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:190 
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x0007f] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:95 
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/IMGUI/GUIUtility.cs:179)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by upgrading my admob plugin